# My download speed is higher than my disk-write speed. What should I upgrade?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My ISP got a new plan now, which allows for 1GBPS internet, that roughly translates to 100MB/s during download speed.

I have a Kingston SSD, and two HDDs (One partioned if it matters), and using the CrystalDisk tool, I checked that even my SSD can barely reach 100MB/s (To be fair, I bought it in 2015).

Considering I use the SSD for my Windows and Steam program installs (Not the games), if I only get a newer SSD with enough space, all I need to do is to point Steam to that new drive? Do I need to reinstall windows on the new drive to make use of it? Or I only need to install Steam program and the games there?

My guess is that I need to install Steam and point the games there, but not Windows, but since I am not sure, here I am.

My processor is an i7 3770K(not overclocked), I have two 8GB HyperX FURY sticks (1600MHz DDR3 CL10 DIMM), the motherboard is a H61M-A/BR. The SSD model is Kingston SV300S37120g, and the HDD's are one SAMSUNG HD103SJ and one WDC WD5000AAKX-00U6AA0, all on Windows 10.

Comment: I have a 1Gbps connection and can't think of any site where I was able to download with more than 50MB/s (fast linux distro mirrors) so I think you don't need to be concerned...

Comment: Really? Is it not possible to reach 100MB/s download speed?

Comment: I didn't say that, just that myself never experienced so high download speeds, don't forget that also all devices share the pipe...and my speedtest got 930Mbps on cable

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. I really wanted to see the download speed to reach 100MB/s, since [Steam does not limit the downloads](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/378847/how-can-i-determine-steam-maximum-download-speed?noredirect=1#comment532387_378847)

Comment: @Zina It's possible to download *many* files from *many* sites simultaneously, so "can't think of any site where I was able to download with more than 50MB/s" is not that relevant.

Comment: @Zina - you've contradicted yourself... 930 Mb/s is much faster than 50 MB/s...

Comment: @Attie - nope, I said my network speed test is 930 while I never experienced downloads faster than 50MBps and set linux distro downloads as an example - and my second comment said that I did not say it is not possible....

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I know - but OP asked for steam so I supposed "single" downloads/connections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Considering I use the SSD for my Windows and Steam program installs (Not the games), if I only get a newer SSD with enough space, all I need to do is to point Steam to that new drive?

It depends on whether or not you're adding the newer SSD to compliment your existing drives or to replace the existing Kingston SSD.

If it's the former, then use disk cloning software to make an exact copy of Windows, Steam and all your other software onto the new SSD and then swap out the drives. Windows will boot as normal and Steam will continue to work. Given that your games are still stored on the HDD then you won't see much improvement in loading times.

If it's the latter then simply add the new SSD in your Steam settings. Go into `Steam -> Settings -> Downloads -> STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS` and then `ADD LIBARY FOLDER` and point it to a folder you've created on your new SSD.

> Do I need to reinstall windows on the new drive to make use of it?

No, see cloning comment above.

If you're replacing the old SSD with a new one then some people use it as an excuse to do a fresh install of Windows to get rid of unused cruft - however it's not necessary in the slightest.